# Как найти значении обрезать дату

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица с колонками Инн и Дата рождения
В колонке Инн первые 6 цифр это Дата рождения
Нужно найти не соответствующие значении, к примеру

```
| iin          | DateofBirth             |
| 710210401978 | 1972-02-10 00:00:00.000 |
```

Comment: Для столбца DateofBirth можно использовать тип `date` (если только вы не используете SqlServer 2005).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
select
    iin, DateofBirth
from
    [TableName]
where
    left(iin, 6) != convert(varchar(6), DateofBirth, 12)
```

(в предположении, что `iin` символьного (`char`/`varchar`) типа, а DateofBirth - `datetime`, а также что `iin` и `DateofBirth` не могут быть NULL).

Третий аргумент в `convert` задаёт форматирование даты в формате ISO `ггммдд` (см. [convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187928.aspx)).

Если `iin` имеет тип `nchar` или `nvarchar`, то первый аргумент в `convert` также лучше сделать `nvarchar` типа, чтобы избежать неявных конвертаций.

---

Применять функцию `FORMAT(DateOfBirth,'yyMMdd')`, предложенную в комментариях в качестве альтернативы `convert`, без оглядки на типы данных столбцов таблицы я бы не стал. И вот почему.

Для таблицы

```
create table TableName (iin varchar(20) not NULL, DateofBirth datetime not NULL);
```

Предикат

```
left(iin, 6) != convert(varchar(6), DateofBirth, 12)
```

транслируется компилятором запросов в

```
substring([iin],(1),(6))<>CONVERT(varchar(6),[DateofBirth],12)
```

Тогда как предикат

```
left(iin, 6) != format(dateofbirth, 'yyMMdd')
```

транслируется в

```
CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(6),substring([iin],(1),(6)),0)
    <>format(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime2(3),[dateofbirth],0),N'yyMMdd')
```

Т.е. при использовании `FORMAT` появляется две дополнительнх конвертации типов.

Впрочем, если тип `iin` будет `nvarchar`, а тип `DateofBirth` - `datetime2`, то дополнительных конвертаций не будет.

Comment: Можно вместо `CONVERT`  использовать `FORMAT(DateOfBirth,'yyMMdd')`

Comment: @Zufir, дополнил ответ. `FORMAT` делает дополнительное неявное преобразование типов `date` и `datetime` к `datetime2`, и возвращает строго `nvarchar` без возможности повлиять на это. В этом смысле `CONVERT` менее прихотливая функция.